# adding the values of two maps when same key

Tags: java, dictionary

Looking for a standard library function way in Java for adding the values in two maps based on their keys.

```
Map A: {a=1, b=2}
Map B: {a=2, c=3}
```

Resulting map:

```
Map C: {a=3, b=2, c=3}
```

I know this can be coded in a few lines. I also know functional programming is great for this. I am just wandering if there is a standard function or syntax people use out there.

Something like (but probably more generic than):

```
 public HashMap<String,Double> addValues(HashMap<String,Double> a, HashMap<String,Double> b) {
    HashMap<String,Double> ret = new HashMap<String,Double>(a);
    for (String s : b.keySet()) {
      if (ret.containsKey(s)) {
        ret.put(s, b.get(s) + ret.get(s));
      } else {
        ret.put(s, b.get(s));
      }
    }
    return ret;
  }
```

---

Comment: This should help you... http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html

Comment: Which datastructure you have? In Question you write `Set`, but you add `map`  tag

Comment: Sorry Jens I meant maps, corrected now.

Comment: It would make your question easier to understand if you replaced *Set* by *Map*. In Java 7 there is no standard method to do this, since it really needs a function argument to combine the values, and that's ugly w/o closures. Maybe it's somewhere in Java 8, but I'm not familiar with the new collection features yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you are doing is just fine. I can think of one other way though, using a [MultiMap](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html). You can add all your elements to a multimap and then run a summation function over all the values for each key at the end.

Answer (score 3):

An alternative which does essentially the same thing, using [Java 8 new `getOrDefault` method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#getOrDefault-java.lang.Object-V-):

```
Set<String> keys = new HashSet<> (a.keySet());
keys.addAll(b.keySet());

Map<String, Integer> c = new HashMap<>();
for (String k : keys) {
  c.put(k, a.getOrDefault(k, 0) + b.getOrDefault(k, 0));
}
```

But if using Java 8, you may as well stream the keys and make it a one liner:

```
Map<String, Object> c = Stream.concat(a.keySet().stream(), b.keySet().stream())
         .distinct()
         .collect(toMap(k -> k, k -> a.getOrDefault(k, 0) + b.getOrDefault(k, 0)));
```

Comment: The Streams solution still seems a bit verbose, but it's nice that it is at least possible now. I would have liked something along the lines of `new HashMap<>().putAll(a).mergeAll(b, (v1,v2) -> v1+v2)`. Can't find anything corresponding to mergeAll in the docs, though. And of course Streams are more general than lots of specialized methods.

Comment: Thanks, very interesting although I was looking for a Java 6/7 solution.

Comment: II don't think you can improve your version much with Java 7.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a version that allows for any number of `Maps` to be combined:

```
public static Map<String, Integer> addKeys(Map<String, Integer>... maps) {
    Set<String> keys = new HashSet<String>();
    for (Map<String, Integer> map : maps)
        keys.addAll(map.keySet());

    Map<String, Integer> result = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
    for (String key : keys) {
        Integer value = 0;
        for (Map<String, Integer> map : maps)
            if (map.containsKey(key))
                value += map.get(key); 
        result.put(key, value);
    }
    return result;
}
```

Usage:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    Map<String, Integer> a = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
    a.put("a", 1);
    a.put("b", 2);
    Map<String, Integer> b = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
    b.put("a", 2);
    b.put("c", 3);

    Map<String, Integer> c = addKeys(a, b);
    System.out.println(c);
}
```

Ouptut:

```
{b=2, c=3, a=3}
```

Unfortunately, it's not possible as far as I can see to create a generic method:

```
 public static <K, V extends Number> Map<K, V> addKeys(Class<V> cls, Map<K, V>... maps);
```

Because the `Number` class doesn't support the `+` operator.  Which seems a bit daft to me...